# Image list is cut off in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, list, internet-explorer-8

grabbed a one-page template the other day and need a hand fixing rendering in IE. Over on the right side, under the Core Values list, the

has an image replacement of the bullets. Looks fine on Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but of course it doesn't on IE. My guess is the margin setting on the

? http://www.justicepartyct.org

Answer (score 0):

The little gold bow image that is being used in place of bullet points is actually quite a bit larger than it appears on the screen.  The size is being reduced using the `background-size`  CSS property.  Unfortunately, IE8 and below do not support `background-size`.

I'm guessing the larger-than-needed size is to make the bullets look sharp on retina  displays.  If you're willing to give that up, do this:

- Resize the bow image to 17px by 17px, like this - [image: resized image]
- Replace the current bow image with the smaller version
- Remove the `-webkit-background-size`, `-moz-background-size`, and
  `background-size` CSS declarations from `li` selectors.  This is optional but good to do
  just to keep things clean.

Comment: Simple or not, it answers your question, right? Can you accept it?